# Fetch scope_identity value in C# code from stored procedure in 3 tier architecture

Tags: c#, sql-server, scope-identity

I need to fetch `scope_identity()` value from a stored procedure after inserting data in C# code.

Here I am using 3 tier architecture. Please anyone help me

```
protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.CreateUserGroups(strGroupName, strDescription, strGroupType);
}

protected void CreateUserGroups(string strGroupName, string strDescription, string strGroupType)
{
    string strReturn = string.Empty;
    strReturn = objUser.SaveCreateGroups(strGroupName, strDescription, strGroupType);
}

public string SaveCreateGroups(string strGroupName, string strDescription, string strGroupType)
{
    try
    {
        DataManager.ParamBuilder param = new DataManager.ParamBuilder();
        if (strGroupName != string.Empty)
            param.AddParam(System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, "@c_groupname", strGroupName);
        else
            param.AddParam(System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, "@c_groupname", DBNull.Value);

        if (strDescription != string.Empty)
            param.AddParam(System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, "@c_description", strDescription);
        else
            param.AddParam(System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, "@c_description", DBNull.Value);

        if (strGroupType != string.Empty)
            param.AddParam(System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, "@n_grouptype", strGroupType);
        else
            param.AddParam(System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, "@n_grouptype", DBNull.Value);


        String strIsUserExitsInGroup = DataManager.ExecuteScalar("sp_create_user_groups", param.Parameters, true).ToString();

        return strIsUserExitsInGroup;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new Exception(e.ToString());
    }
}

public static object ExecuteScalar(string procedureNameOrSql, List<SqlParameter> parameters, bool isStoredProcedure)
{
    object scalarValue;
    using (SqlConnection cn = createConnection())
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(procedureNameOrSql, cn);
        if (isStoredProcedure)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        if (parameters != null)
            cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters.ToArray());
        scalarValue = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }
    return scalarValue;
}
```

My stored procedure:

```
CREATE Procedure [dbo].[sp_create_user_groups]
  @n_user_group_id int OUTPUT,
  @c_groupname varchar(200),
  @c_description varchar(200),
  @n_grouptype int
As
   Declare @IsGroupNameExists int,        
           @b_active bit

   select @IsGroupNameExists = 0
   set @b_active = 1

BEGIN
IF exists(select top 1 * from gdt_user_groups where c_group_name = @c_groupname)
BEGIN
 select @IsGroupNameExists = 1
END
ELSE
 BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    insert into gdt_user_groups(c_group_name,c_description,n_group_id,b_active,d_modified_dttm,
    d_created_dttm)values(@c_groupname,@c_description,@n_grouptype,@b_active,GETDATE(),GETDATE())
    select @n_user_group_id = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
    select @IsGroupNameExists = 0
 END 

 select @IsGroupNameExists
 END
```

Here where exactly I can fetch the the scope_identity value in C# code. Anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get value through output parameter, so you must follow these link:
[Get output parameter value in ADO.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290652/get-output-parameter-value-in-ado-net)
[How to use OUTPUT parameter in Stored Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7770924/how-to-use-output-parameter-in-stored-procedure)

> you just need to create a SqlParameter, set the Direction to Output,
>   and add it to the SqlCommand's Parameters collection. Then execute the
>   stored procedure and get the value of the parameter.

While adding parameter do as below after adding extra parameter in your method

```
param.AddParam(SqlDbType.Int, "@c_Id", IdValue, ParameterDirection.Output);
```

then access the value of your output parameter as below:

```
object value = cmd.Parameters["@c_Id"].Value;
```

**Source:** [Getting the identity of the most recently added record](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/54/Getting-the-identity-of-the-most-recently-added-record)
Code Snippet:

```
string query = "AddCategory";
int ID;
string connect = @"Server=.\SQLExpress;Database=Northwind;Trusted_Connection=Yes;";
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connect))
{
  using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
  {
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Category", Category.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@CategoryID", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "CategoryID");
    cmd.Parameters["@CategoryID"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    ID = (int)cmd.Parameters["@CategoryID"].Value;
  }
}
```

procedure...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddCategory
  -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
  @Category NVARCHAR(15),
  @CategoryID INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  -- Insert statements for procedure here
  INSERT INTO Categories (CategoryName) VALUES (@Category)
  SET @CategoryID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
END
```

Hope the above reference help you more to understand all of this.

Comment: The variable `@n_user_group_id` is however an output parameter for the stored procedure.

Comment: @Niranjan Kala ok. how can i fetch that value in C# code.Bcoz here i am using Sqlcommand in different layer as it will used by other functions so i cant fetch value of scope identity at that stage????

Comment: i have updated my answer.. check this. now it is more relevent