# Cannot return value from SQL Server using Scope_Identity() in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, scope, return

I'm using the following code and SQL to try and return a value from an insert statement, but to no effect.

Can anyone help, please.

The c# is:

```
Int32 newProdID = 0;

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(GlobalVar.ConnectionStringDev);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_save_test", con);
con.Open();

cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@one", one));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@two", two));
cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

cmd.Connection = con;

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

string id = cmd.Parameters["@id"].Value.ToString();

return newProdID;
```

and my SQL Server stored procedure is:

```
@one varchar(255),
@two varchar(255),
@id int output
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table_2]
([One],[Two])
VALUES
(@One,
@Two)

SET @id=SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Many thanks

G

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fetch scope\_identity value in C# code from stored procedure in 3 tier architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416811/fetch-scope-identity-value-in-c-sharp-code-from-stored-procedure-in-3-tier-archi)

Comment: That SP definition looks incomplete.

Comment: Please try this: 
   SELECT @id=SCOPE_IDENTITY()
   return @id
END

Comment: OR simply end the sp with END

Comment: @Bikram `RETURN` isn't for returning things like the value of `SCOPE_IDENTITY`.

Comment: The only way of returning a value is by using a parameter which will associate procedure variable newProdID to the paramters.  See output parameter : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/return-data-from-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Thanks Bikram...all sorted, :)