# Stored procedure doesn't return output

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a simple stored procedure which inserts a users record in a table and should give out its userid.

Here is the stored procedure:

```
 Alter proc spRegistration
     @UserId nvarchar(10) output,
     @Name nvarchar(20),
     @EmailAdd nvarchar(20)
 as
 begin
     Declare @Count int;
     Declare @ReturnCode int

     Select @Count = Count(EmailAdd) 
     from tblAllUsers 
     where EmailAdd = @EmailAdd

     if @Count > 0
     begin
         Set @ReturnCode = -1
     end
     else
     begin
         Set @ReturnCode = 1

         Insert into tblAllUsers(Name, EmailAdd) 
         values(@Name, @EmailAdd)
     end

     Select @UserId = UserId 
     from tblAllUsers 
     where EmailAdd = @EmailAdd

     Select @ReturnCode as ReturnCode
 end
```

I try to get the `userid` into a textbox like below :

```
 string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["hh"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spRegistration", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailAdd", txtEmailAddress.Text);
        var UserID = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
        UserID.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        int ReturnCode = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        if (ReturnCode == -1)
        {
            lblRegMessage.Text = "This email has already been registered with us.";
        }
        else
        {
            lblRegMessage.Text = "You were registered successfully.";
            txtUserId.Text=(String)UserID.Value;
        }
```

The table as well as the stored procedure is far too complex,I have simplified it for better understanding of problem.UserId is Alphanumeric.Dont worry about that.

Putting a break point shows a null against var UserID
Where am i going wrong?

Comment: cmd.Parameters["@UserId"].Value.ToString();... instead of UserID.Value. I am guessing you are doing a "Var UserID before executescalar" thats why its not giving value.

Comment: see this, as well.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7770924/how-to-use-output-parameter-in-stored-procedure

Comment: You should add the line SET NOCOUNT ON as the first line of the stored procedure. Without this every SELECT statement in your SP returns a rowset to your client with number of rows affected (DONE_IN_PROC)

Comment: `ExecuteScalar` is not the robot you are looking for.

Comment: @Hogan but it worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to Use `.ToString()` on `UserID`

```
txtUserId.Text= UserID.Value.ToString();
```

EDIT:

```
var UserID = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", SqlDbType.NVarChar,50);
```

Comment: String[16]: the Size property has an invalid size of 0.

Comment: @MukeshPanwar You need to define a length when specifying the varchar parameter. See updated code