# Procedure has no parameters and arguments were supplied 3

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

The stored procedure returns one value:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spCaller]
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @URL nvarchar(255);  

    EXECUTE spBuscarUrl 'MIREX-2017-00001', @url = @URL OUTPUT;  

    SELECT @URL
END
```

When I'm trying to show the value using ASP.NET, I get an error:

> Procedure spCaller has no parameters and arguments were supplied

This is my C# code:

```
try
{  
    string s = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dba"].ConnectionString;

    SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(s);
    conexion.Open();

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spCaller",conexion))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@URL", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Label1.Text.Trim();

        object o = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

        if(o != null)
        {
            string id = o.ToString();
            lblTitulo.Text = "Completed";
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw new Exception(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use OUTPUT parameter in Stored Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7770924/how-to-use-output-parameter-in-stored-procedure)

Comment: Please include the source code of `spBuscarUrl`.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is pretty clear that your stored procedure  does not expects any parameter while from c# code you are passing parameter.

Actually you have specified a variable in your stored procedure not a parameter, you will need to specify it just after the SP name parameter with it's datatype and in your case `OUTPUT` keyword as it output parameter.

It should be :

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[spCaller] @URL NVarChar(255) OUTPUT
.......
.......
```

Your final stored procedure would be like:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[spCaller] @URL NVarChar(255) OUTPUT
AS BEGIN
EXECUTE spBuscarUrl  
    'MIREX-2017-00001', @url = @URL OUTPUT;  
select @URL
END
```

You can have a look at [this post](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/163/returning-stored-procedure-parameter-values-to-a-calling-stored-procedure/) explaining how to pass different kind of parameters to a Stored Procedure.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

This line is the error:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@URL", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Label1.Text.Trim();
```

`@URL` is not a param in your stored procedure.

Check the correct syntax here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql

```
CREATE PROCEDURE What_DB_is_that 
     @ID int   
AS    
    SELECT DB_NAME(@ID) AS ThatDB;
```